# Why don't new clipped or merged QGIS shapefile layers display their names in layers table?

Tags: qgis, layers

QGIS 2.18.12 - When I use the Clip or Merge Shapefile tools in QGIS, the set of Shapefiles is created with my chosen name and in the folder I have designated.
However, in the Layers Panel, the layer is shown as 'Clipped' or 'Merged'.  Is there a good reason for this?  Wouldn't it be clearer if the Shapefile name was shown instead?  It can be confusing if I have more than one clipped or merged layer.

Comment: Should have said 'Layers Panel' in heading.

Comment: Please [Edit] your question instead of commenting on it.

Answer (score 4):

Under "Processing" menu -> "Options" look for the "Use filename as layer name" option (under 'General' settings):

[image]

Tick that on and you'll get the behavior you desire.